# AppleScript - Minimize all windows based on processName and windowTitle

Tags: applescript

I am trying to loop through all the processes and get the windowTitle of each process's Main window. Based on the windowTitle, I want to make the process Hide().

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with aProcess in processes
        tell aProcess
           tell (1st window whose value of attribute "AXMain" is true)
              set windowTitle to value of attribute "AXTitle"
              if windowTitle is not "stackoverflow" then
                set visible of aProcess to false
              end if
           end tell
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

I am getting

```
execution error: System Events got an error: Can’t get window 1 of item 1 of every process whose value of attribute "AXMain" = true. Invalid index. (-1719)
```

Is it because of all the processes not having a Main Window?

Comment: This happens when application is in PresentationMode

Comment: Change `tell aProcess` to `tell process aProcess`

Comment: @vijay No, that’s incorrect. `aProcess` is assigned a value that references a `process` object already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because of all the processes not having a Main Window?

It's more to do with not all processes having windows (of any kind).

```
tell application id "com.apple.systemevents" to tell (every process ¬
        whose front window's class = window and the front window's ¬
        title does not contain "foobar") to set visible to true
```

#### Breakdown:

- **`tell application id "com.apple.systemevents" to`:** Directing commands to *System Events*.  The only difference is I've referred to the application by its bundle identifier instead of its name.  It's not hugely important, but an application's bundle identifier is less likely to change than is its file name.
- **`tell (every process whose front window's class = window`:** This is an effective way to retrieve a list of processes that have at least one window, as it filters out processes with no windows for whom `class of its front window` will be `missing value`.
- **`and the front window's title does not contain "foobar"`:** Having filtered processes down to only windowed applications, this further filters it by the name/title of the window.  The `title` property gets its value from the `attribute "AXTitle"`, but accessing a property an `attribute` object.  Here, I elected to relax the equality that you impose on matching a window's title, so that you needn't use the full title of the window, but rather a sensibly chosen word of your choosing.
- **`to set visible to true`:** Hides the processes returned earlier